# How to convert a Seq of tuples into set's of individual elements Scala

Tags: scala, tuples, scala-collections

We have a sequence of tuples `Seq(department, title`) `depTitleSeq` we would like to extract `Set(department)` and `Set(title)` looking for the best way to do so far we could come up with is

```
val depTitleSeq = getDepTitleTupleSeq()
var departmentSeq = ArrayBuffer[String]()
var titleSeq = ArrayBuffer[String]()
for (depTitle <- depTitleSeq) yield {
  departmentSeq += depTitle._1
  titleSeq += depTitle._2
}

val depSet = departmentSeq.toSet
val titleSet = titleSeq.toSet
```

Fairly new to scala, i'm sure there are better and more efficient ways to achieve this if you could please point us in the right direction it would of great help

Comment: Why down-voting ? before you downvote if you could please let the user know why you are down-voting it would help in improving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val result:(Set[String], Set[String]) = depTitleSeq.foldLeft((Set[String](), Set[String]())){(a, b) => (a._1 + b._1, a._2 + b._2) }
```

you can use `foldLeft` to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer,  but getting syntax error at >> (Set(), Set())

Comment: Can you please explain the syntax error at >> (Set(), Set())

Comment: @user2359997 this is **type signature**.

Comment: Surely `unzip` is a better than `foldLeft` in this situation?

Comment: @Tim yeah, it's better

Comment: This will rebuild a new set for every added element, which is even more wasteful than unzipping and then invoking `toSet` two times. You might try to set up two `mutable.SetBuilder`s if you want to avoid the creation of any intermediate structures. Moreover `Set.empty[String]` might help to reduce the number of parentheses.

Answer (score 4):

If you have two `Seq`s of data that you want combined into a `Seq` of tuples, you can `zip` them together.

If you have a `Seq` of tuples and you want the elements separated, then you can `unzip` them.

```
val (departmentSeq, titleSeq) = getDepTitleTupleSeq().unzip

val depSet   :Set[String] = departmentSeq.toSet
val titleSet :Set[String] = titleSeq.toSet
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val depTitleSeq = Seq(("x","a"),("y","b"))
val depSet = depTitleSeq.map(_._1).toSet
val titleSet = depTitleSeq.map(_._2).toSet
```

***In Scala REPL:***

```
scala> val depTitleSeq = Seq(("x","a"),("y","b"))
depTitleSeq: Seq[(String, String)] = List((x,a), (y,b))

scala> val depSet = depTitleSeq.map(_._1).toSet
depSet: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(x, y)

scala> val titleSet = depTitleSeq.map(_._2).toSet
titleSet: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(a, b)
```

Comment: missing `.toSet`.